# Google API - Gmail. Downloading attachments

Tags: c#, google-api, google-apis-explorer

When calling this method please help by advising what values to pass through such as GmailService? Im guessing userID is the Gmail account and the messageID( i want to download all of them) .

How can i change this to download all the attachments in the inbox.

Thank you in advance and I hope someone can help me.

Method im using is below.

```
public static void GetAttachments(GmailService service, String userId, String messageId, String outputDir)
{
  try
  {
    Message message = service.Users.Messages.Get(userId, messageId).Execute();
    IList<MessagePart> parts = message.Payload.Parts;
    foreach (MessagePart part in parts)
    {
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(part.Filename))
      {
        String attId = part.Body.AttachmentId;
        MessagePartBody attachPart = service.Users.Messages.Attachments.Get(userId, messageId, attId).Execute();

        // Converting from RFC 4648 base64 to base64url encoding
        // see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history
        String attachData = attachPart.Data.Replace('-', '+');
        attachData = attachData.Replace('_', '/');

        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(attachData);
        File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(outputDir, part.Filename), data);                        
       }
     }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
   }
 }
```

Comment: this does look like its getting all attachments it takes a message and gets the parts..

Comment: But does it run through the whole inbox? And what do i pass in the parameter section?

Comment: no you need to go through each mail yourself, its only 1 additional thing

Comment: Ok, thank you. But I still dont know whatto pass as values when calling the function.

Comment: So having not worked with gmail api - its after your service, the user ID, a messageid (which is the id of the email) and where to write it, there will be an api to get a list of message IDs from the inbox, get that, foreach it.. and pass it to this.

Comment: This really helps thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

**I think the answer to your question can be solved using Get in PostMan**

> In your header in PostMan, use key as Authorization and pass your token generated to it as value
>   or goto Authorization and pick bearer token and pass your token.
>    Note that messageId is the Id in string of the message you are trying to fetch and {userId} =me or user according to google and I believe you can fetch Attachment Id by the method you use above.
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/messageId/attachments/id

```
 public async Task<TResult> GetGmailInboxAttachmentById<TResult>(string messageId, string token, string id, string attachId)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/" + messageId + "/" + id + "/attachments" + "/" + attachId;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);


            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TResult>();

        }
    }

foreach (var part in inbox.Payload.Parts)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(part.Filename))
                    {
                        var attachId = part.Body.AttachmentId;
                        var attach = _gmailService.GetGmailInboxAttachmentById<MessagePartBody>(id, token, part.PartId, attachId).Result;
                        // Converting from RFC 4648 base64 to base64url encoding
                        // see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history
                        string attachData = attach.Data.Replace('_', '+');
                        attachData = attachData.Replace('_', '/');
                        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(attachData);
                        string file = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
                        GetAttach.Add(file);



                    }
                }
```

Hope this solve it for you because I solved it with this method

Answer (score 1):

I know, it's could be an off-topic, but using PostMan in case when programmer use Google API is little but contraproductive :) APIs also have attachments.Get Method, and you will not need to call HTTP request and allow non OAuth 2.0 authentication especially when you're using multi-phase authentication.

Here is example:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get

Comment: Link only answers are not considered good practice. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Please consider adding snippets from the doc to demonstrate how your answer can help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var part in m.Payload.Parts)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(part.Filename))
    {
        var attachId = part.Body.AttachmentId;
        MessagePartBody attachPart = service.Users.Messages.Attachments.Get(userId,
                                                                            message.Id,
                                                                            attachId).Execute();
        byte[] data = GetBytesFromPart(attachPart.Data);
        File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(@"c:\teste\", 
                                        $"{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}-{part.Filename}"), data);
    }
}

private static string DecodedString(string messagePart)
{
    try
    {
        var data = GetBytesFromPart(messagePart);
        string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
        return decodedString;
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        // ignored
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

private static byte[] GetBytesFromPart(string messagePart)
{
    var attachData = messagePart.Replace('-', '+');
    attachData = attachData.Replace('_', '/');
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(attachData);
    return data;
}
```